# Collapsible SliverAppBar with no intermediate states

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a collapsible SliverAppBar that has an expanded state and a collapsed state and no intermediate states. That means that you cannot scroll down a little bit and leave the app bar in a partial transition. When left in this position it should animate either to a collapsed or expanded state based on where it's going to land.

The scroll position should automatically adjust itself to match. In other words, if the app bar expands it should simultaneously push the content down with it.

Answer (score 1):

`SliverAppBar` has a `snap` property.

The official documentation has a number of animations showing different combinations of `snap`, `pinnend`, and `floating`: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html

Comment: This doesn't adjust the scroll position to match. Edited the question for clarity. Thanks.